# mongodb replica set is ok but does not replicate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I've created my mongodb replicaset and all is correct except is not replicate in remote host, but I've tried to access remote pc at the port 27017 and working properly.
I created the database on the remote PC to see if this solved but nothing, I have also inserted new records but nothing, Any ideas?

rs.status()

```
{
    "set" : "meteor",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-03-08T16:14:24.181Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(3),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "172.27.10.13:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 6920,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1457453535, 2),
                "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-03-08T16:12:15Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1457446744, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-03-08T14:19:04Z"),
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

rs.conf

```
rs.conf(    rs.config(
meteor:PRIMARY> rs.config()
{
    "_id" : "meteor",
    "version" : 1,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "172.27.10.13:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you expecting to to replicate _to_? You only have a single database server as a member of this replica set.

Answer (score 1):

According to your configuration settings you didn't add any other members (secondaries, arbiters etc.) to your replica-set configuration. Beacuse of this mongodb has no way of knowing ***where*** to replicat to.

Try adding your remote host to the replica-set configuration like this:

```
rs.add("your-remote-host:port")
```

See: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/